# Covert Time to total seconds

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I want to create a new column 'Time' from an existing 'TimeMajor' column which will contain time in the form of total seconds and its contents will be of integer type. For instance,

```
00:00:05 = 5 secs
00:14:10 = 850 secs
02:30:10 = 9010 secs
```

Code:

```
data["TimeMajor"] = pd.to_datetime(data["created_at"])
data['Time'] = data.TimeMajor.dt.time
data['Time'].timedelta.total_seconds()
```

which gives:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-d7912fbaf9b4> in <module>()
----> 1 data['Time'].timedelta.total_seconds()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5272             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5273                 return self[name]
-> 5274             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5275 
   5276     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'timedelta'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert to `timedelta` dtype first, using the string equivalent of the `time` component from your `datetime` colum 'data["TimeMajor"]':

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'TimeMajor': pd.to_datetime(['2020-06-12 02:30:10'])})

data['Timedelta'] = pd.to_timedelta(data['TimeMajor'].dt.time.astype(str))

data['Timedelta'].dt.total_seconds()
# 0    9010.0
# Name: Timedelta, dtype: float64
```

or straight to a column 'Time':

```
data['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(data['TimeMajor'].dt.time.astype(str)).dt.total_seconds()
```

...or if you have a reference date from which you want to count seconds, you don't even need to convert to timedelta explicitly:

```
refdate = pd.to_datetime('2020-06-12')
data['Timedelta'] = data['TimeMajor'] - refdate
```

Comment: Thank you. Though this is specific to a date. I want to implement it to entire column. So what should be the general syntax to convert entire column values into seconds? And I want those seconds values in integer type so that I can do my visulaizations effortlessly

Comment: @KankshaDhakate you mean not only the time component but also the date? then what is your reference date?

Comment: No no. Just the time to be in seconds and not date. But the 1st line after importing pandas in the solution given by you, it is date specific and I want to pass entire column of time which shall contain time in the format hr:min:sec. So what should be the column oriented syntax?

Comment: In your question, 'TimeMajor' is a column of datetime objects, did I get that correctly? This will always contain a date component if you use it or not. Anyways, I made an edit, maybe that helps.